# C#, SQL Server. Provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known

Tags: c#, sql-server

My connection string looks like this:

```
Data Source=sql88;Initial Catalog=Osm;User ID=foouser;Password=foopsw
```

The code that creates connection string looks like this:

```
var con = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Username) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Password))
    con.IntegratedSecurity = true;
else
{
    con.UserID = model.Username;
    con.Password = model.Password;
}
con.DataSource = model.Host ?? string.Empty;
con.InitialCatalog = model.Database ?? string.Empty;
return con;
```

My application creates database structure at SQL Server, then inserting data. So sometimes the applcation works approximately 14 hours. The code that executes SQL at SQL Server looks like this:

```
using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandTimeout = int.MaxValue;
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var test = ex.Message;
        throw;
    }       
}
```

**Sometimes application works well**, but sometimes application throws an error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>
> provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.) (Microsoft
>   SQL Server, Error: 11001)

I've read [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15), however, in my view this is not my case because **sometimes** my application works well.

Comment: spotty wifi? If it works sometimes, but still get this error, it may be because your computer is getting disconnected from the network. Try pinging the target SQL server when you get the error to make sure you're still connected and target server is operational.

Comment: @Madushan thank you for your resplonse! However, we are using `Ethernet`, not WiFi. Maybe other ideas?

Comment: Ethernet can still disconnect. I think its still worth testing by pinging when you get the error. Or run a ping loop in the background in a batch file or so, as you work, and see if you get dropped pings when you get the error.

Comment: @Madushan ok, thanks, Madushan, I will do it!

Comment: Yes, this sounds like a networking problem, not an application problem. If you can't get infrastructure to diagnose and correct the problem, you could implement retry logic in your application code.